# Do while string validation (with multiple strings)

Tags: java

For some reason, when I have multiple correct strings, the statement keeps repeating

```
    do {
    System.out.println("Enter Service Code");
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    serviceCode = a.nextLine();
} while (!serviceCode.equals("ORB1") || !serviceCode.equals("ORBH") || 
         !serviceCode.equals("ISS5") || !serviceCode.equals("ILLOYDS") || 
         !serviceCode.equals("DLAB") || !serviceCode.equals("LEOM7") || 
         !serviceCode.equals("MOON2"));
```

However, when there's just one string that the code checks against. The do while statement works fine and will stop looping when the correct input is entered

```
    do {
    System.out.println("Enter Service Code");
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    serviceCode = a.nextLine();
} while (!serviceCode.equals("ORB1"));
```

Comment: Put System.out.println("-"+serviceCode) after you call a.nextLine() and you will know why^^

Comment: take a look at your condition. Let's say you input `"ORB1"`. Then, `!serviceCode.equals("ORB1") = False`, because they're equal. But, what about the others? They keep returning `True`, because they're not equal.

Comment: bcoz all those other ors will be true

Comment: **Please don't instanciate a `Scanner` in a loop !!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter "ORB1", "!serviceCode.equals("ORB1")" will return false but the others will return true; and you are using the "OR" operator. So, this sentence :

```
!serviceCode.equals("ORB1") || !serviceCode.equals("ORBH") || 
     !serviceCode.equals("ISS5") || !serviceCode.equals("ILLOYDS") || 
     !serviceCode.equals("DLAB") || !serviceCode.equals("LEOM7") || 
     !serviceCode.equals("MOON2")
```

will always be true. You need to use the "AND" operator

```
!serviceCode.equals("ORB1") && !serviceCode.equals("ORBH") && 
     !serviceCode.equals("ISS5") && !serviceCode.equals("ILLOYDS") &&
     !serviceCode.equals("DLAB") && !serviceCode.equals("LEOM7") && 
     !serviceCode.equals("MOON2")
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I looked over that one

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison can never return false. it's either A or B.

so, if you were to say:

```
if ( !A OR !B ){
```

> --> Input = A => true (because !B returns true)
>   --> Input = B => true (because !A returns true)
>   --> Input = C => true (because !A returns true)

Change your OR (`||`) by AND (`&&`)

Also: declare and instantiate your `Scanner` before your loop.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be create a `List`of string which includes the valid codes and check if that list `contains` the provided user input.

```
List<String> validServiceCodes = Arrays.asList("ORB1", "ORBH", "ISS5", "ILLOYDS", "DLAB", "LEOM7", "MOON2" );

do {
    System.out.println("Enter Service Code");
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    serviceCode = a.nextLine();
} while (!validCodes.contains(validServiceCodes));
```